# Why the ZIP APPNOTE on PKWARE website didn't mentioned the correct password check mechanism in their specification?

Tags: zip

I have been reading the PKWARE legacy `password check mechanism` in [APPNOTEs](https://support.pkware.com/display/PKZIP/Application+Note+Archives) available. At the end of section **6.1.6** *Decrypting the encryption header*, the paragraph states the following:

> After the header is decrypted,  the last 1 or 2 bytes in Buffer
>       SHOULD be the high-order word/byte of the CRC for the file being
>       decrypted, stored in Intel low-byte/high-byte order.  Versions of
>       PKZIP prior to 2.0 used a 2 byte CRC check; a 1 byte CRC check is
>       used on versions after 2.0.  This can be used to test if the password
>       supplied is correct or not

The above paragraph mentioned only the 1 or 2 bytes check with `CRC` but **didn't mentioned** that it could also be a check for `last mod file time` instead of `CRC`, based on `bit 3` of the `general purpose bit flag`.

I have encrypted a file using `zip 3.0` on linux machine using default `Traditional PKWARE Encryption` and  after following decryption process, i came to realize that the last one or two bytes should be checked with `last mod file time` instead of `CRC` to check whether the password is correct or not.

After searching for sometime on web, i only found this version of [APPNOTE](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/doc/appnote-iz-latest.zip) which actually describes that the check could be either for `CRC` OR `last mod file time` depending on `bit 3`  of `general purpose bit flag`.

Does the linux `zip 3.0` doesn't follow the PKWARE APPNOTE standard or the PKWARE didn't mentioned about the above information ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the linux zip 3.0 doesn't follow the PKWARE APPNOTE standard or the PKWARE didn't mentioned about the above information ?

Both are true.
PKWARE doesn't feel compelled to add third-party changes to their standard.
But thank you for having found any documentation about this time-stamp byte. I had some headaches about this for my own implementation, before realizing, by looking into Info-Zip's source code, that they had replaced the CRC byte by a time-stamp byte (a good idea, by the way).